# React MaterialUI Theming | How to increase transition duration when switching theme?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am making a light/dark theme using React MaterialUi.

**Question:** Is there any possibility to ease theme transition speed instead of instant transition ?

**Problem:**

- I've already tried inline styling with style={{transition: "all 1s linear}} in the parent div **but it only works on text color and not the background color (still switches instantly)**
- I also tried to override transitions duration in createMuiTheme({transitions: {/ /}}) but it has no effect

Comment: Does adding the transition property to the body element in a global CSS file work?

Comment: @Calvin Thanks a lot! It worked with the "overrides" property inside createMuiTheme({/ /})  + <CssBaseline />.
NB: I had to append extra inline styling for the <AppBar />, not sure why this component does not inherit from body transition ...

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

If you are using CssBaseline to reset global styling, you can also define new rules inside createMuiTheme({}) to define a global body {transition: "all
0.5s linear"}.

- Global Css reset with CssBaseline

  ```
  export default function Layout({ children }) {
    const {
      state: { darkMode },
    } = useContext(AppContext);
    const theme = darkTheme(darkMode);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <div
        style={{
          minHeight: '100vh',
          boxSizing: 'border-box',
        }}>
        <Navbar />
        {children}
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
  ```

  }
- New Global css "overrides" inside createMuiTheme()

  ```
    export const darkTheme = (dark: boolean): ThemeOptions => {
    const paletteColors = dark ? paletteColorsDark : paletteColorsLight;

    return createMuiTheme({
      palette: {
        type: dark ? 'dark' : 'light',
        primary: {
          main: paletteColors.primary,
        },
        secondary: {
          main: paletteColors.secondary,
        },
     /////// IMPORTANT PART //////////////////////////////////////////
    },
      overrides: {
        MuiCssBaseline: {
          '@global': {
            body: {
              transition: 'all 0.3s linear',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });
   };
  ```

**NB:** you may need some extra inline styling for specific elements (AppBar in my case)

```
    <AppBar
      position='static'
      color='default'
      elevation={1}
      style={{ transition: 'all 0.3s linear' }}>
      {/* */}
    </AppBar>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  }
```

Add this to your top-level CSS import. This might be an `index.css` and then `import "./index.css";` is in the `main.jsx` (or wherever you have stuff like: `<React.StrictMode>`).

I see this was covered in the comments in the original question.